# Calculate : $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_{n}(x)\phi (x)\,dx$

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, limits, distribution-theory

defined sequence function :

$$f_{n}(x)=\begin{cases}-n^{2},-\frac{1}{n}<x<0\\n^{2},0<x<\frac{1}{n}\\0,\operatorname{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Find

$a)$ $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to +\infty}f_{n}(x)$

$b)$ for $\phi \in D$ find the following limit :

$$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to +\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_{n}(x)\phi (x)dx=?$$

My try for first question 
:

Fix $x$ , then for all $|x|≥\frac{1}{n}$ then $\lim_{n\to +\infty}f_{n}(x)=0$

Is my solution correct ?

I have a problem always to find this limits of this type definition

And what about second Limit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation of the first limit is correct.

Assuming that you by $\phi \in D$ mean that $\phi$ is differentiable, we can compute the other limit as;
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_n(x) \phi(x) dx = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}n^2 (\int_0^{\frac1n}\phi(x)dx-\int_{-\frac{1}{n}}^0\phi(x)dx) $$
Now since $\phi$ is continuous the function $\Phi(y):=\int_0^y \phi(x)dx$ is differentiable with $\Phi'(y)=\phi(y)$ (by the fundamental theorem of calculus). This means that the limit above can be written as 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}n^2 (\int_0^{\frac1n}\phi(x)dx-\int_{-\frac{1}{n}}^0\phi(x)dx) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\Phi(\frac{1}{n})+\Phi(-\frac{1}{n})}{\frac{1}{n^2}}$$
Noting that $\Phi(0)=0$ we can use L'Hospitals rule twice to compute
$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{\Phi(h)+\Phi(-h)}{h^2}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{\phi(h)-\phi(-h)}{2h} = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{\phi'(h)+\phi'(-h)}{2}=\phi'(0) $$

Comment: Very  nice sir $LeanderTilstedKristensen